# I can't use the data from another class and display in Outlook htmlBody

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working on the following code to determine the user's Name and show at the bottom of the email. The code is working perfectly, I just don't know how to get the name and put it on HtmlBody from another class.

Right now, it's showing the result in the Console.

```
public void GetCurrentUserInfo()
    {
        Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
            Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
        if (addrEntry.Type == "EX")
        {
            Outlook.ExchangeUser currentUser =
                Application.Session.CurrentUser.
                AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
            if (currentUser != null)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("Name: "
                    + currentUser.Name);
           
                Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I am close with this following code? Which feels so wrong!

```
mailitem.HTMLBody = "<html><body> </br><div class="Name", +sb.ToString()></br></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLBody` property value represents a well-formed HTML document. So, you need to find the closing `</body>` tag and insert your data before it. Use the `InStr` function available in VBA:

```
Sub FindWord()
Dim Position As Integer
Position = InStr(1, HTMLBody, "</body>", vbBinaryCompare)
MsgBox Position
End Sub
```